# Apply similar function to multilevel pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multilevel dataframe of the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'A',2,'B',1,'B'],[2,'B',2,'B',2,'A'],[1,'A',1,'A',1,'A'],[1,'B',2,'A',2,'B']],
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('S1','Num'),('S1','Let'),('S2','Num'),('S2','Let'),('S3','Num'),('S3','Let')]))

   S1      S2      S3    
  Num Let Num Let Num Let
0   1   A   2   B   1   B
1   2   B   2   B   2   A
2   1   A   1   A   1   A
3   1   B   2   A   2   B
```

How can I create a new dataframe such that for choice of each level zero column, if Let=='B' then it sets Num = 3? Basically I would like to get the following dataframe:

```
   S1      S2      S3    
  Num Let Num Let Num Let
0   1   A   3   B   3   B
1   3   B   3   B   2   A
2   1   A   1   A   1   A
3   3   B   2   A   3   B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to work positionally and use `iloc` and `where`:

```
>>> df.iloc[:,0::2] = df.iloc[:,0::2].where((df.iloc[:,1::2]!="B").values, 3)
>>> df
   S1      S2      S3    
  Num Let Num Let Num Let
0   1   A   3   B   3   B
1   3   B   3   B   2   A
2   1   A   1   A   1   A
3   3   B   2   A   3   B
```

This uses the array

```
>>> (df.iloc[:,1::2]!="B").values
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

to decide where we need to leave the original values alone.  We have to stick `.values` in there because otherwise pandas tries to align the frame, and we're doing it manually.

If you insist on not using iloc, well, things get a little trickier.  One way would be to use `xs` and `update`:

```
>>> df.update(df.xs("Num", level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).where(
              df.xs("Let", level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).values != "B", 3))
>>> df
   S1      S2      S3    
  Num Let Num Let Num Let
0   1   A   3   B   3   B
1   3   B   3   B   2   A
2   1   A   1   A   1   A
3   3   B   2   A   3   B
```

Or if your columns were lexsorted, you could use `loc` with `slice(None)`:

```
>>> df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
>>> nummask = slice(None), "Num"
>>> letmask = slice(None), "Let"
>>> df.loc[:, nummask] = df.loc[:, nummask].where((df.loc[:, letmask] != "B").values, 3)
>>> df
   S1      S2      S3    
  Let Num Let Num Let Num
0   A   1   B   3   B   3
1   B   3   B   3   A   2
2   A   1   A   1   A   1
3   B   3   A   2   B   3
```

This could be simplified somewhat using IndexSlice:

```
>>> df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
>>> idx = pd.IndexSlice
>>> df.loc[:,idx[:,"Num"]] = df.loc[:,idx[:,"Num"]].where((df.loc[:,idx[:,"Let"]] != "B").values, 3)
>>> df
   S1      S2      S3    
  Let Num Let Num Let Num
0   A   1   B   3   B   3
1   B   3   B   3   A   2
2   A   1   A   1   A   1
3   B   3   A   2   B   3
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But is there a way to do this without using iloc? I mean by using the column names instead of their numbers?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. This was what I was looking for.